# Why can't I get the text with Cheerio in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, cloudflare, cheerio

Why can't I get the text of the website?
And the result is some message when I executed.

Is that the website being locked?

```html
<!-- Checking if the site connection is secure -->

<div id="challenge-error-title">
    <div class="h2">
        <span class="icon-wrapper">
            <div class="heading-icon warning-icon"></div>
        </span>
        <span id="challenge-error-text">
            Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The message I get is:

```
www.wantgoo.com needs to review the security of your connection before proceeding.
Ray ID: 79cc6ad74d162844
            
Performance & security by Cloudflare
```

My script is sample.

```js
function myFunction() {

  const url = 'https://www.wantgoo.com/stock/3218';

  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true }).getContentText();
  const $ = Cheerio.load(res);

  Logger.log($('body').text());
}
```

Comment: Yup, looks like you're being blocked by the server, with or without a user agent (503: Service Temporarily Unavailable). What data are you ultimately trying to get? You might need to use a browser automation lib like Puppeteer, but I'm not sure if that runs in Google Apps Script.

Comment: hmm..it's a stock website can be realtime to know the price. So I'd want to get the price(number) from that website. But it's seem can't read the soure code with cheerio in google apps script.

Comment: Cheerio's not the problem, it's that the request returns plain static HTML, no JS. That site appears to be a JS-based SPA. Print `res` and see what it looks like.

Comment: That's cloudflare in "under attack" mode. You're not likely to get that even with puppeteer.

Comment: Oh...So I have to give this websit and looking at someone else....